# How to add custom message after core message?

Tags: php, magento

I can display custom messages by:

```
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($msg);
```

it works in general, but not if it is followed by a default Magento message like:

```
$this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('The address has been saved.'));
```

then only the core message would show up.

How can I display both messages?

Comment: well, I discovered I can omit the conflict between both messages by changing the event from `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_address_index` to `customer_address_save_commit_after`, but I'm not sure if I will be able to solve this issue this way every time.

Comment: You are doing that in backend panel. Am I right?

Comment: no, in my module's `Observer.php`

Comment: Ok. What $this->_getSession() returns?